# Exporting/Importing a Table of complex numbers

Tags: export, import, complex, list-manipulation

I'm generating a long table of list of the form:

`PN={{1,2,1+i},{3.5,2.6,2}...},{...},...`

Using:

`Export["PN.dat", PN, "Table"]`

Seems to do the job of exporting, but then using:

`PN = Import["PN.dat", "Table"]  or PN = ReadList["PN.dat"]`

Can't reconstruct the same List, the first way considers the imaginary number i as something else "I", while the second one returns insane data like:

`{{-1., -2.6464*10^-40, 0. + 2.76621*10^18 I}, {-0.129967...`

Any ideas how to do this right? (Using ToExpression Returns $Faild)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the root of $-1$ is represented as `I`, not `i`.

In any case, the technique I use to export arbitrary data structures is to compress, save, load and uncompress:

```
ClearAll@PN;
PN = {{1, 2, 1 + I}, {3.5, 2.6 - 0.8*I, 2}}
Export["~/Desktop/PN.txt", Compress@PN]
{#, Im@#} &@Uncompress@Import@"~/Desktop/PN.txt"

(*{{{1, 2, 1 + I}, {3.5, 2.6 - 0.8 I, 2}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, -0.8, 0}}}*)
```

Comment: Congrats on 10k rep !

Comment: @Artes thank you!