# Sound data Import Export

Tags: export, import, sound

Can't regain the data after Export.

Create an array of sampled amplitude values:
2. Visualize as sound
3. Save it
4. Get it back
5. ???

```
sound = RandomReal[1, {500}];  
ListPlay[sound]  
Export["test.txt", sound];  
in=Import["test.txt"]  
ListPlay[in]
```

A second example.
Take data from a WAV sound,
Export it,
reImport it,
play it.

```
tubadat = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}, "Data"];  
Export["TubaDat.dat", tubadat];  
in = Import["TubaDat.dat"];  
ListPlay[in]
```

It is not the original sound.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15495/16)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Export["~/Desktop/test.txt", Compress@sound]` and `in = Uncompress@Import["~/Desktop/test.txt"]`. The way you did it, it gets imported as a string. There's other ways, but the one I present is what I always use to export/import arbitrary data structures: it's cross-platform and robust (as far as I can tell).

Regarding the second example and the comments:

```
tubadat = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}, "Data"]; 
ListPlay[tubadat, SampleRate -> 22050] 
Export["~/Desktop/TubaDat.txt", Compress@tubadat]; 
in = Uncompress@Import["~/Desktop/TubaDat.txt"]; 
ListPlay[in, SampleRate -> 22050, PlayRange->{-1,1}] 
tubadat == in
```

works; the sounds seem identical and `tubadat==in` evaluates to `True`. **Note that setting the sample rate is necessary** (it defauls to 8k).

To summarise, you need to

- make sure you're importing in the right format (your original code ended up importing as a string)
- fix the sample rate as it defaults to the wrong values for this case.
- possibly fix the max amplitude (otherwise the sample is amplified or clipped)

Comment: Unfortionatly it does not work.                  Please take the second example in my question.            The sound when reimported is distorted.

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon If I do `tubadat = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}, "Data"];
ListPlay[tubadat, SampleRate -> 22050]
Export["~/Desktop/TubaDat.txt", Compress@tubadat];
in = Uncompress@Import["~/Desktop/TubaDat.txt"];
ListPlay[in, SampleRate -> 22050]
tubadat == in` then the sounds seem identical and `tubadat` is literally the same list as `in`. did you a) use `txt` instead of `dat` (I guess yes)? b) set the sample rate correctly in `ListPlay`

Comment: OK. . . . I now see where the real culprit is located. . . .     It is already distorted when importing the Data in tubadat = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}, "Data"]; Compare it with ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}]. . . Here it goes wrong.

Comment: are you sure it's not just a question of setting the sample rate? it defaults to 8192Hz

Comment: OK.  . .see  .  . ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}] . . take. . tubadat = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba", SampleRate -> 22050]; .  . see .  . ListPlay[tubadat]

Comment: It is like the the entire peak range is compressed.

Comment: The Data shown in ListPlay are by far not the original amplitude values as shown in  ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}]

Comment: `ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba", SampleRate -> 22050];` has a syntax error. My point, anyway, was that `ListPlay[tubadat]` plays `tubadat` as if it's sampled at 8KHz, while in fact it's sampled at 22KHz. Also, looking at the plots, they're identical, as far as I can tell. Why do you say that the data shown isn't the same?

Comment: Compare the original.   .   .ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}].  . .  . with the extracted data from .  .  .  . tubadat = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"},"Data"]; .  .  . by locking at.  .   .   .ListPlay[tubadat]

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon I see, maybe `ListPlay[tubadat, SampleRate -> 22050, PlayRange -> {-1, 1}]` then

Comment: Great acl!!  . .  .  We got it!! .  .  .Nice work.  .  .

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 3):

The 4th line needs correction:

```
in = Import["test.txt", "Data"] // Flatten
```

Now it will work - you need to read up on [**import/export of data**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html) on Documentation. This is fixes your specific code. But there are many ways to do this. For example to use "test.dat" format is better (no "Data" specification needed in Import). Or exporting sound itself (not the data) will work too - with the advantage that you can play it in other software:

```
data = RandomReal[1, 500];
sound = ListPlay[data];
Export["test.wav", sound];
Import["test.wav"]
```

[image]

Comment: The solution by .dat works fine here.

Comment: The solution by .dat works fine here.  But I encounterd the problem in a task, where not the sound itself has to be exported but only the data. And later on the data has to be imported back. Here is the example. First we got a wav-sound:     tuba = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}];     We extract the data:   tubadat = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Tuba"}, "Data"];    Export["tubaDat.dat", tubadat];    in = Import[tubaDat.dat];    ListPlay[in]            As you see, the replay of the imported file is distorted.